# Why am I seeing a blue screen with "kernel auto boost lock with raised irql" message on my Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10

At the instant of using the touchpad, on the user sign-in window, a blue screen with the given message snaps into view. I have updated my touchpad device drivers, but the problem still persists. Since my reputation is low, I cannot upload the image. So, I am describing it here.

1. There is a progress-percentage of some kind saying that we are collecting information.
2. A bar code
3. Stop - Code : Kernel auto boost lock with raised irql.

[image]

Comment: You can upload the photo elsewhere (e.g. on Imgur) and provide a link.

Answer (score -1):

### Blue Screen of Death

A "blue screen" (or "stop error") is what's commonly known as the Blue Screen of Death (BSOB), and it could appear while upgrading to a new version of the OS, when starting your computer, or just "out of the blue" when using Windows 10.

The biggest issue with a blue screen is that it's literally a screen with a blue background and a sad face with not enough information to tell you the problem.

You'll usually (not always) see a message that reads: "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you." And a general error code (HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAID, PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGE_AREA, CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED or BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO, for example) that can give you a clue of the issue. But most of the time it's not enough to fix the problem.

Fortunately, you can often narrow down the blue screen to a problem with an update for Windows or a bad driver, incompatible software, or hardware you recently configured.

To troubleshoot the BSoD caused by this error code you can follow one of the methods in this post:

Source : [Fix: BSOD Caused by ‘Kernel Auto Boost Lock Acquisition With Raised IRQL’](http://windowsreport.com/bsod-kernel-auto-boost-lock-acquisition-with-raised-irql/)

### Solution 1 – Disable your wireless adapter

To do so follow these instructions:

1. Go to Device Manager. You can do so by pressing Windows Key + X and choosing Device Manager from the menu.
2. In device manager locate your wireless adapter, right click it and disable it.

Try and see if the issue is resolved.
If this works for you, you might have to use Ethernet connection instead of wireless. In addition, you might want to remove your wireless adapter if you know how to do it and if your computer isn’t under warranty, or temporarily use a different wireless adapter. This isn’t necessary, and in most cases disabling the adapter should do the trick. As far as we know Atheros AR928X Wireless network adaptor is causing the issues, but other models might have issue as well.

Some users also advise to uninstall your Wireless adapter drivers and allow Windows 10 to find them on its own.

### To uninstall drivers do the following:

1. Open Device Manager and locate your wireless adapter.
2. Right click it and choose Uninstall.
3. Check Delete the driver software for this device and click OK.
4. After you restart your computer Windows 10 should install the default drivers on its own.

### Solution 2 – Disconnect your Bluetooth devices

Before turning on your computer make sure that you disconnect all Bluetooth devices from your computer. If the problem still persists, you can try uninstalling and disabling the Bluetooth driver on a similar way as we mentioned in previous solution.
For information on bluetooth drivers you visit this link:

[Fix: Bluetooth is Not Working in Windows 10](http://windowsreport.com/bluetooth-not-working-windows-10/)

### Solution 3 – Remove DNAS device from your system

According to the users Ximeta won’t develop new drivers so your best solution is to remove DNAS device from your system. After doing that the BSOD error should go away.

As you can see, this issue is annoying but we expect Microsoft to fix it with latest Windows 10 patch, so make sure that you keep your Windows 10 up to date with latest patches.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.